# codename one android app is blinking like white flash and than opened

Tags: android, codenameone

When I am trying to open android app which is developed using codename one framework, app is blinking like white flash and than opened.

I tried with 
  `Display.getIntance().setFramerate(30)` code on start() method and init() method, but it could not resolve my problem.

Is there any resolution for this.

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't call setFramerate but it's unclear what your app does? Are you drawing? Are you using images? Do you understand the concepts of the EDT?

Comment: How is your application different from a hello world app or a typical Codename One demo?

Comment: Shai Almog , we have used the Forms to display. We used to initialize the form on start() method instead of calling StateMachineBase class initialization.
Can you suggest we done it in wrong way??

Comment: Sorry for some reason I didn't see the response comment... That shouldn't be a problem unless you go back and forth with code. Can you post some of what you did?